# resize column across multiple rows using html grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've got a grid layout with 2 columns and 3 rows.

I want to be able to resize the column widths. I know I can use `resize: horizontal` but that only changes width for one row.

I'm thinking I can't do what I want and I'll need to use nested grids but I'm not sure so I wanted to check.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
                grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
                gap: 0px 0px;
                grid-auto-flow: row;
                grid-template-areas:
                    "logo search"
                    "nav main"
                    "log main";
            }

            .logo {
                grid-area: logo;
            }

            .search {
                grid-area: search;
            }

            .nav {
                grid-area: nav;
                overflow: auto;
                resize: horizontal;
            }

            .log {
                grid-area: log;
                overflow: auto;
                resize: horizontal;
            }

            .main {
                grid-area: main;
            }


            html,
            body,
            .container {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }

            /* For presentation only, no need to copy the code below */

            .container * {
                border: 1px solid red;
                position: relative;
            }

            .container *:after {
                content: attr(class);
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: grid;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="search"></div>
            <div class="nav">

            </div>
            <div class="log"></div>
            <div class="main"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with your structure. The trick is to use `auto 1fr` on the template columns and set the initial width of the resizable element to be equal to `50vw` to simulate the `1fr 1fr` initially:

<sup>PS: I simplified the code by removing the areas but that's not part of the trick, you can keep it</sup>

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.log {
  overflow: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
  width:50vw;
}

.main {
  grid-row:2/span 2;
  grid-column:2;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}


/* For presentation only, no need to copy the code below */

.container * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.container *:after {
  content: attr(class);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="search"></div>
  <div class="nav">

  </div>
  <div class="log"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

If you will have content, you can do it like below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.log {
  overflow: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
  width:50vw;
}
/* disable the width contribution so only the log will define the width */
.logo,
.nav {
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
/**/
.main {
  grid-row:2/span 2;
  grid-column:2;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}


/* For presentation only, no need to copy the code below */

.container * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur .</div>
  <div class="search"> </div>
  <div class="nav">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  </div>
  <div class="log"> </div>
  <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to make it so only `nav` and `log` column resize but `logo` column does not, is that possible with grid? I assume not.